# Override xcircuit's button bindings

Tags: drawing

I'm using XCircuit on my laptop running Ubuntu. Since getting middle mouse button action using touchpad is not easy I want to configure xcircuit configuration file. But due to lack of examples I'm unable to the get the desired result. I want to "start wire" with "w"(already defined), "finish" with "e" and "select box" using "Hold_q". Also I want to start the windows in fullscreen.
This is how my current `.xcircuitrc` file looks like

```
xcircuit::keybind e { finish }
xcircuit::keybind Hold_q { select box }
```

But tcl console is giving me following errors.

```
invalid command name "finish"
invalid command name "finish"
    while executing
"finish  "
    invoked from within
"if {![xcircuit::keyaction 26 16]} {  finish  }"
    (command bound to event)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. XCircuit defines the key sequence Shift-Button1 as an alternative to the middle mouse button.
2. XCircuit started with the option "-2" remaps the button and key bindings. In this case, all bindings for "mouse button 2" or the "middle mouse button" will be remapped to the right mouse button, and all bindings for the right mouse button will be remapped to the backspace key.

Alternatively, `.xcircuitrc` options should be like the following

```
xcircuit::keybind e { action "finish" }
xcircuit::keybind l { action "select box" }
```